# Laravel - How to Toggle checkbox and update the field in the database

Tags: jquery, laravel

Currently, I am developing a web application in Laravel-5.8. In the project I need to set the current appraisal using a checkbox. The checkbox field is is_current and is tinyint (boolean).

By default, it is zero(0). If the checkbox is checked from the view as current, in the database it should turn the field is_current of that particular row to 1. Then all other is_current in the database should be set to zero(0). And also save it in the database.

**Controller**

```
public function create()
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('appraisal_identity_create'), 403);
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_identities.create');
}

public function store(StoreAppraisalIdentityRequest $request)
{   
    $identity = AppraisalIdentity::create([
        'appraisal_name' => $request->appraisal_name,
        'is_current'     => $request->is_current,
    ]);
    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal is created successfully');
    return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index');
}
```

**View**

```
<form  action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                     <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Is Current Appraisal?</label>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="form-control"  name="is_current" value="{{old('is_current')}}">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <!--<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ trans('global.save') }}">-->
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

How do I adjust my controller and view to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try to get the value of your checkbox if this way:

```
'is_current' => (bool) $request->get('is_current', false);
```

`(bool)` parse the value of the checkbox as `true` if it is checked.
If it is not checked it will be return `null` but it is parsed as `false` and Laravel will insert it as `tinyInt` 1 (true) or 0 (false).

You may also check if in your `AppraisalIdentity` model the field `is_current` is declared as fillable.

**Note**: this method works only if you submit the form with a submit button (the commented submit button that you have in your view).

If you would like to set the value with jQuery you have to use Ajax, create a new route and the row in your table must be exists.

Comment: If is_current is 1 (true), how do I now toggle or change any other is_current in the database to 0. There can only be one is_current = 1

Comment: You have to rewrite your code because the `store` function creates an object every time you call it. What do you want to do? Create a new row? Update a row? Or set all the `is_current` fields in every row as 0 if it is not checked?